# Django StaticLiveServerTestCase tests fail when run together

Tags: django, integration-testing, django-testing

There are two tests both of then do the same thing log a user in if, if I run ever test individually but if I try to test the whole class the first passes and the second one gives `Server Error ( 500 )`

All of the tests involve the `user` logging in I tried creating users locally in each test but that didn't work either is any help is appreciated.

```
class SomeTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username="user1",password="somepassword")
        self.user.save()
        qrt, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name="A Team")
        qrt.user_set.add(self.user)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_user_can_login(self):
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
        user = self.browser.find_element_by_id("id_username")
        pa   = self.browser.find_element_by_id("id_password")
        user.send_keys("user1")
        pa.send_keys("somepassword")
        pa.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        title = self.browser.find_element_by_id("title").text
        self.assertIn(title, "Welcome")

    def test_user_can_login_again(self):
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
        user = self.browser.find_element_by_id("id_username")
        pa   = self.browser.find_element_by_id("id_password")
        user.send_keys("user1")
        pa.send_keys("somepassword")
        pa.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        title = self.browser.find_element_by_id("title").text
        self.assertIn(title, "Welcome")
```

Comment: can you set `DEBUG=True` and see error log?

Comment: I did So it seems I found the problem, for every test my `setUp()` creates a new user and a new group so when I try to see if a user a `user` is in a certain group, the groups name is the same but it is a new entry in the database. so my `if group in user.groups.all()` doesn't work.